# email link to collect feedback form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow where I am taking advantage of the Collect Feedback Action. What I am trying to do is add a link to an email that the user can click to take them directly to the form. So far my searches have not turned up any results.

here is the step within my designer workflow:
[image: collect feedback]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to do this by inserting a link and using the string builder to concatenate the url with the current item id. Something like

http://mysite/mylist/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]

Should work.

The only caveat is that it wont open in dialog. Though you may be able to do this in javascript